# I want to know the difference between 'the west ' and ' west'. I want to know the meaning of 'the'

Tags: definite-article

I have a question about 'the'.

I wanna know the difference between the west and west.

Comment: "I would like to know..." is more polite than saying "I wanna know". The latter is acceptable in *speech* but rarely in writing, and never for requests.

Answer (score 7):

“West” is a direction/orientation, e.g., “west of the city”, “we’re driving west”.

“The west” refers to the western area of a given place, e.g., the western part of a country or a town. For example, in my home country, England, the city of Manchester is in “the west.”

The word “the” indicates that there is/can be one and only one “west”. E.g., a country, theoretically, only has one westerly part, which, in that context, we can refer to as “the west”.

“The west” can also commonly refer to “[the western world](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_world)”, e.g., in politics.

Answer (score 5):

Chris Mack is entirely right in his answer. There are a third, fourth, and maybe more options. There is West, the west, the West, The West, etc. It is all based on context and to whom you are speaking. Here are some examples:

- West is a cardinal direction that is to an observer’s left when the observer is facing North.
- Then, there is the west as a place that is West of another specific place or just West relative to you.
- “The West“ in the U.S. will refer to a specific area as well as time in American history. This would include the central area of the United States between the 1600’s and 1900’s. It would exclude the original 13 colonies and the Pacific Coast. Quintessentially, it is typified by the “Old West” and ”Wild West” of cowboys and indians, cattle, Texas, and the U.S Territories prior to them officially becoming states.
- Although, many in Asia will use the term “the West”, they are usually referring to the countries West of the former Soviet Union, and predominantly Anglo-European influenced (including North and South America and Oceania. The Middle East would be its own area. Africa would be its own area, and the Far East would be its own area.
- Although many in Europe will use the term “the West”, they are usually referring to the U.S. as the West. Even though there are other countries in the Western Hemisphere. And, even though other areas East of Europe would include Europe in the term.
- As a tangent, the term “Western” in America not only can mean media centered around or based upon the time period mentioned above. It is also a cultural reference to a fashion or manner of dress, speech, decor, music (even though the music is not necessarily about the time period), etc.

Similar comparisons can be made for terms such as:

- North
- South
- The North
- The South
- Southside
- Southsiiiiede
- Central South
- The Southwest
- The Dirty South
- South Central (playa)
- Etc.